# Give the precise meaning of $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = +\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Give the precise meaning of the limit- $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = +\infty$$ (x is going to negative infinity, the symbol is hard to see)

I know that as $x$ gets smaller and smaller, $f(x)$ gets larger and larger, but how do I put that in terms of a precise definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is standard:

> For any $M > 0$, there exists $K < 0$ (usually sufficiently small) such that for all $x < K$, it holds $f(x) > M$.

To make analogy to the normal function limit, you might also treat $-\infty$ as a special point, whose neighbors are $(-\infty, x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^1$.

Answer (score 0):

It means that, for all $M\in\Bbb R$ there exists $H\in\Bbb R$ such that for all $x<H$ it holds $f(x)>M$. In symbols:
$$\forall M\in\Bbb R,\exists H\in\Bbb R\ \ \forall x<H,\ f(x)>M$$